# Adding whitespace to text elements

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

is there a way to add whitespace to each elements that contain text? 
For this example:

```
movie <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/") 
cast <- html_nodes(movie, "#titleCast span.itemprop")
cast %>% html_structure()
[[1]]
<span.itemprop [itemprop]>
  {text}

[[2]]
<span.itemprop [itemprop]>
  {text}
```

I would want to add a trailing whitespace to each text element **before** using `html_text()`. I have another use case where I want to use `html_text()` higher up in the document hierarchy. The result is that several texts get combined within one vector element. This makes it impossible to infer start and end of the corresponding parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
doc <- minimal_html("Hello<p>World</p>") 
doc %>% html_text # HelloWorld
doc %>% html_text_collapse(" ") # Hello World
```

If so here is the code:

```
require(stringi)
require(rvest)

html_text_collapse <- function(x, collapse = " ", trim = TRUE){
  text <- html_text(html_nodes(x, xpath = ".//text()[normalize-space()]"))
  if (trim) {
    text <- stri_trim_both(text)
  }
  paste(text, collapse = collapse)
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much! :) Would you mind briefly explaining how this code chunk works? I'm not familiar with ````UseMethod()````.

Comment: @methodds: Just simplified the function. Have a look here on how the old one worked: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#s3

I realised that i coded that for a special usecase of mine. The above should be fine for most usecases...

Comment: Thank that's even better in also something I understand.